# How to keep several local copies of a theme in sync?

Tags: framework, sync

I am working on several sites on a local installation of apache/mysql, using virtual hosts.
I have created a child theme for twentyeleven and I want to use that child theme like a framework for all my sites locally.

My question are :

1. How can I keep all the copies of my "framework" automatically up to
       date, in sync?
2. What would be better suited than twentyeleven to create a child
       theme from, and use it as a framework?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

as for your first answer , Like always, you can do that in many ways..
you can

- use a local folder synch
- write a function to allow wp to use a themefrom other install (3 filters to check : template_directory_uri // theme_root //theme_root_uri )
- install a multiblog network mode  and use the same theme for all.

IMHO the best would be to to use local folder synch...

for your second answer , In my experience (and it is very individual) all frameworks / empty themes / blank files only complicate the work (unless you know them very good ) 
It is always better to start from scratch (depending on your level of course )
The only time I tried to use an empty / blank "framework" it took me 4 times as much time to develop the site than it usually does ... but like I said, it is personal , and also depends on the complexity of your design or site (the more complex, the faster you should drop the idea of "frameworks"

Comment: +1 for "from scratch" - or at least, your own "base" theme that you can start each project with (a few functions and basic HTML). I would *never* use TwentyEleven as a framework, it's more of a showcase of *everything* WordPress can do.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, 1. Folder sync -> Ok. Will look into a solution for mac. Any suggestion other than Folderwatch? 2. Where should i look for best "from scratch" practices and structures? Is boilerplate something to consider? Roots? Starkers?

Comment: first - I have never worked on a mac, and hope I never will, so I can not help you with that ... as for the starkers, roots etc, the whole point of "from scratch" is exactly to avoid those things .. from scratch means open notepad and start coding ... the only references you need is the codex ,and sites like this one here whenre you can find custom functions that you might need ..